# Django and urls.py: How do I HttpResponseRedirect via a named url?

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-urls

I'm writing a member-based web application, and I need to be able to redirect the page after login. I want to use the named url from my urls.py script in my views.py file for the login application, but I can't for the life of me figure out what to do. What I have is this:

```
def login(request): 
if request.session.has_key('user'):
    if request.session['user'] is not None:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/path/to/page.html')
```

What I want to accomplish is something like:

```
def login(request): 
if request.session.has_key('user'):
    if request.session['user'] is not None:
        return HttpResponseRedirect url pageName
```

I get syntax errors when I execute this, any ideas?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to use the [`reverse()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) utils function.

```
from django.urls import reverse
# or Django < 2.0 : from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def myview(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('arch-summary', args=[1945]))
```

Where `args` satisfies all the arguments in your url's regular expression.  You can also supply named args by passing a dictionary.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! I must have just been searching through the django docs all wrong.

Comment: It's `from django.urls import reverse` these days.

Comment: @partofthething I've updated the answer to include a commented out import

Answer (score 15):

The right answer from [Django 1.3 onwards](http://web.archive.org/web/20140704183041/https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), where the redirect method implicitly does a reverse call, is:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def login(request):
    if request.session.get('user'):
        return redirect('named_url')
```

Comment: Also, if you are using a named app within your project, the syntax is `redirect('appName:urlName')`

Answer (score 7):

A more concise way to write that if statement would be `if request.session.get('user')`. has_key is deprecated nowadays, and .get() returns None (by default, changeable by passing a second parameter).
So combining this with Soviut's reply:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def login(request): 
    if request.session.get('user'):
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my-named-url'))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def login(request):
    if request.session.get('user'):
        return redirect(reverse('name-of-url'))
```

Also see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls